# Why json parsing serializer is not working for nested json in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am implementing json API using Django Rest Framework.
Since sqlite is being used for database, json data is stored as string and when the  data is requested, serializer parse the string and convert into json and sent to client side. This implementation worked for simple json file as shown in left picture. However, this cannot work for nested json as shown right picture.
Can anyone tell me how I should revise serializer in order to work for nested json also?
[image]

**serializer.py**

```
class strToJson(serializers.CharField):

    def to_representation(self,value):
        x=JSON.loads(value)
        return x

class summarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project=serializers.CharField(read_only=True,source="html.project")
    version = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="html.version")
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source="html.pk")
    json = strToJson()

    class Meta:
        model=summary
        fields=('id','project','version','json')
```

**model.py**

```
class summary(models.Model):
    html = models.ForeignKey(html, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='summaries')
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='test')
    json = models.TextField(default='test')
```

Comment: It does not answer the question, but have you tried using `JSONField` with `binary=True` instead of your custom `strToJson`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: You JSON serialize the data twice, so it is not a JSON blob the second time, but a string literal.

Comment: @stellasia I tried but it didnt work...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how I should revise this serializer to solve the problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I got what you mean and could solve the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @KatsuyaObara, can you post an answer if you managed to solve your problem please? Thanks.